# Given the rank of a matrix, determine matrices B and C such that BAC=H

Tags: matrices

Matrix $H=
\begin{bmatrix}
    I_{3}       & (0) \\
    (0)       & (0) 
\end{bmatrix}$

Matrix $A=
\begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
    1 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\
    1 & -1 & 2 & 0 \\
    2 & 0 & 0 & -2
\end{bmatrix}$

Use elementary transformations to transform $A$ to $H$. Given these matrices, determine matrices $B$ and $C$ so that $BAC=H$. The following identity may be important: $A=B^{-1}HC^{-1}$

When I try to transform $A$ into $H$, I get the following:
Matrix $A=
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

How do I get $A$ to $H$ and complete the problem from here?

Thank you.

Comment: Note that $\ker A$ is the span of $(1,-1,-1,1)^T$.

Comment: @copper.hat can you please expand on this a little? I cannot see how this relates yet.

Comment: @copper.hat we have not yet learned what a ker is

Comment: Are you familiar with elementary row/column operations?

Comment: @copper.hat yes, Gaussian elimination only

Answer (score 1):

With a sequence of elementary row operations $E_3 E_2 E_1 A$ is an upper triangular matrix. With two elementary column operations $E_3 E_2 E_1 A C_1 C_2$ is a diagonal matrix
$\Delta=\operatorname{diag}\{ 2, -1, 1, 0 \}$. With $D=\operatorname{diag}\{ {1 \over 2}, -1, 1, 1\}$, we see that
$(D E_3 E_2 E_1 ) A ( C_1 C_2) = \operatorname{diag}\{1,1,1,0\}$.

The $E$s are elementary row operations and the $C$s are elementary column operations. For example, I chose
$E_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
-{1 \over 2} & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
-{1 \over 2} & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$,
$C_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & -{1 \over 2} & 0 \\
0 & 1 & {1 \over 2} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: I just want to ensure that I understand this correctly, since some notation is new to me. What are $E_i$'s and $C_i$'s? Additionally, how do I find which operations to execute?

Comment: It appears that your designation of $E_3E_2E_1A$ is what I have obtained in my posted question. Is this correct? If so, which column operators do I execute to obtain $\Delta=$diag{2,-1,1,0}?

Comment: Just apply the transpose of the operators used to do row operations. After performing the elementary row operations, I ended up with [2 0 1 -1 ; 0 -1 1/2 -1/2 ; 0 0 1 1 ; 0 0 0 1].